# Spark - Strange characters when reading CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I hope someone could help me please. My problem is the following:

To read a CSV file in Spark I'm using the code

```
val df=spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("/home/user/Documents/filename.csv")
```

assuming that my file is called `filename.csv` and the path is `/home/user/Documents/`

To show the first 10 results I use

```
df.show(10)
```

but instead I get the following result which contains the character � and not showing the 10 results as desired

```
scala> df.show(10)
+--------+---------+---------+-----------------+                                
|     c1|      c2|      c3|              c4|
+--------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|��1.0|5450|3007|20160101|
+--------+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

The CSV file looks something like this

```
c1  c2      c3     c4

1   5450    3007    20160101

2   2156    1414    20160107

1   78229   3656    20160309

1   34963   4484    20160104

1   7897    3350    20160105

11  13247   3242    20160303

2   4957    3350    20160124

1   73083   4211    20160207
```

The file that I'm trying to read is big. When I try smaller files I don't get the strange character and I can see the first 10 results without problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the default charset encoding of spark is UTF-8, you are sure that your csv files encoding is UTF-8 ?

Comment: Hmm Ok, apparently the encoding of my file is UTF-16. I will try to change it (if possible) and try again

Comment: You also might want to apply a `trim` to your data. Weird characters can get shoved into a CSV when you open it in Excel for example.

Comment: I can't convert my file to UTF-8. It's big enough to crash LibreOffice and Notepadqq when I'm trying to re-save it. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is not the problem caused by settings of Spark. Try to re-save(save as) your CSV file as "CSV UTF-8 (comma delimited)", then rerun your code, the strange characters will gone. I had similar problem when read some CSV file containing German words, then I did above, it is all good.